# Using Post Thumbnail with Fancybox

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, fancybox

I'm trying to set my page so that when a user clicks the thumbnail of the current post, it expands in a Fancybox popup.

```
<?php 
    $featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID);
?>

<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
    <div class="featured-image" data-fancybox="gallery" href="<?php $featured_img_url ?>"
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

This works, in that the image opens as expected when it's clicked. But when I click off the overlay, the thumbnail has disappeared. `display: none` has been added to it inline.

I have also tried wrapping the div in an `<a>` tag and using that, but this has the same outcome.

```
<?php 
    $featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID);
?>

<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
    <a href="<?php $featured_img_url ?>" class="fancybox" data-fancybox="gallery">
        <div class="featured-image bShadow">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        </div> 
    </a>
<?php } ?>
```

I have other images on the page assigned with Advanced Custom Fields that work fine with Fancybox, so I'm assuming the issue is with how I'm trying to get the thumbnail image using `php`.

Edit: Here's a video of the current outcome: https://www.useloom.com/share/f525f4f0e4c642c8800e82532a99e326

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not correct url for your featured link and it is treated as "inline" content instead of "image".

Anyway, you could follow this demo - https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/VGoRqO?editors=1010 - and use "trigger element" feature by adding `data-fancybox-trigger` attribute for featured link.